# What's the difference between -a and -e in a zsh conditional expression?

Tags: zsh

I was looking up the meaning of flags like `-a` in zsh `if` statements, eg.

```sh
if [[ -a file.txt ]]; do
    # do something
fi
```

and I found [this](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html)

> -a file
>
> true if file exists.
>
> -e file
>
> true if file exists.

What is the difference between `-a` and `-e`? And if there is none, why do they both exist?

Comment: I think there is no difference; `-a` may have been an option used by an older shell and supported by `zsh` for script compatibility, and now it's retained for backwards compatibility with older versions of `zsh` itself.

Comment: Should this question be on super user? I didn't think of that until after I posted it

Comment: It's a gray area; usage and scripting overlap heavily when it comes to shells.

Comment: @chepner You may as well post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) sheds some light on this.

tl;dr: Ksh traditionally used `-a` and several other shells followed suit. POSIX instead borrowed  `-e` from Csh to avoid confusion. Now many shells support both.

> The `-e` primary, possessing similar functionality to that provided by the C shell, was added because it provides the only way for a shell script to find out if a file exists without trying to open the file. Since implementations are allowed to add additional file types, a portable script cannot use:
>
> ```
> test -b foo -o -c foo -o -d foo -o -f foo -o -p foo
> ```
>
> to find out if foo is an existing file. On historical BSD systems, the existence of a file could be determined by:
>
> ```
> test -f foo -o -d foo
> ```
>
> but there was no easy way to determine that an existing file was a regular file. An early proposal used the KornShell `-a` primary (with the same meaning), but this was changed to `-e` because there were concerns about the high probability of humans confusing the `-a` primary with the `-a` binary operator.

Comment: And ironically, `-a` was never made required and is now considered obsolete :) `-e` seems like a much better name, though, anyway.